# Is it possible to create a unique account with nodemailer, even if sharing the same process?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm using [nodemailer](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer), and noticed that calling:

```js
nodemailer.createTestAccount();
```

does not create a unique account, if the call happens in the same node process.

Is it possible somehow, to guarantee a unique test account on each call?

Answer (score 1):

I have checked source code of nodemailer, seems like you can pass environment variable to node process which will control this behaviour, such as:

```
ETHEREAL_CACHE=no ...
```